# What does "opengl" in qt download name indicate?

Tags: qt, opengl, download, naming-conventions

In the file

```
qt-opensource-windows-x86-msvc2012_64_opengl-5.2.1.exe
```

from [qt downloads](http://download.qt.io/official_releases/qt/5.2/5.2.1/qt-opensource-windows-x86-msvc2012_64_opengl-5.2.1.exe.mirrorlist)

what does the "opengl" indicate?

Also, where can info on the naming convention for the file be found?

Answer (score 3):

On Windows, Qt can be configured to use OpenGL directly, or to use [ANGLE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANGLE_%28software%29), which translates OpenGL calls to DirectX calls.The `opengl` in the file name indicates that the installer ships a build for "native" OpenGL. 
The Qt Wiki [explains it in more detail](https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_5_on_Windows_ANGLE_and_OpenGL).

Comment: So then does `qt-opensource-windows-x86-msvc2012_64-5.2.1.exe` this version uses ANGLE?  If so, I'm assuming this version `qt-opensource-windows-x86-msvc2012-5.2.1.exe` is just the 32 bit version that also uses ANGLE.  Is this correct?

Comment: IIRC yes. The latter is compiled as 32bit, yes.